# Javascript not reaching end of array

Tags: javascript

Ive got a really strange problem with some javascript code that ive written. I have set this code to execute on load. The idea of it is to remove a value from a text field if it is listed in another field. Here is the code:

```
var diseases = document.getElementById("AffectedBy").value;  
        var diseasearray = diseases.split("-");  
        alert("disease array size: " + diseasearray.length);  
        for (i=0;i<diseasearray.length;i++)  
            if (diseases.match("-" + diseasearray[i]))  
                {  
                    diseasearray[i] = "-" + diseasearray[i];  
                    alert(diseasearray[i]);                           
                    document.getElementById("DiseaseNotSelected").value=document.getElementById("DiseaseNotSelected").value.replace(diseasearray[i],"")
                }
```

This code above gives an array size of 3 (1 blank, and 2 values) but when I display the values in the alert it only shows 2 values(1 blank, and 1 value)

This piece of code:

```
var foods = document.getElementById("FoodFor").value;  
        var foodarray = foods.split("-");  
        alert("food array size: " + foodarray.length);  
        for (i=0;i<foodarray.length;i++)  
            if (foods.match("-" + foodarray[i]))  
                {  
                    foodarray[i] = "-" + foodarray[i];  
                    alert(foodarray[i]);  
                    document.getElementById("FoodNotSelected").value=document.getElementById("FoodNotSelected").value.replace(foodarray[i],"")
                }
```

This code above gives an array size of 3 (1 blank, and 2 values) and when I display the values in the alert it only shows 3 values(1 blank, and 2 value).

Can anyone see a reason why the first code block only shows 2 items in the array as I cant see why and its really bugging me now.

Comment: Could you post the HTML code of `AffectedBy` and `DiseaseNotSelected`?   Also, beware that whatever you pass into [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will get turned into a regular expression.  If that contains some special character, it might not match where you would expect it to (or vice versa).

Comment: Ok, A bit more detail, the first code block is analysing this string as AffectedBy: **-Fin Rot-White Spot (Ich)-Gill Rot** The result comes back as: **-White Spot (Ich)-Test-Blue Sturgeon Test Disease** but it should show **-Test-Blue Sturgeon Test Disease**. The second one analyses this as FoodFor: **-Hikari Wheatgerm Sinking Pellet** and returns **-Tetrapond Sticks-New Food-New Food 2-New Food 3** which is correct as they are the other items. For these results the array sizes are (respectively) 4 and 2

Comment: @martijn - I think you've hit the nail on the head, the only one it seems to play up with is **WhiteSpot (Ich)** is there a way I can get round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above: beware that whatever you pass into [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will get turned into a regular expression. If that contains some special character, it might not match where you would expect it to (or vice versa).

The string `White Spot (Ich)` will be turned into the regex `/White Spot (Ich)/`; which does *not* match `White Spot (Ich)` but *does* match `White Spot Ich`, since the parentheses are grouping operators in a regex.

Change the regular expression test

```
diseases.match("-" + diseasearray[i])
```

into the plain string comparison

```
diseases.indexOf("-" + diseasearray[i]) !== -1
```

and you should be set.

(I think.  :-)

Comment: You sir are an absolute legend. this has worked perfectly. I am a beginner to all of this so I am learning the javascript as I go along.

Comment: @Stefan: Glad I could help. :-)  In matters of Javascript, the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) and [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) are not to be missed.

Answer (score 4):

the first one is running a match against a string starting with '-'.

I don't have your actual values, but let's say that the value of #AffectedBy is "test1-test2-test3".

the first alert will be 3, because the diseasearray will have three components (test1, test2, test3)

you then run through a loop (0, 1, 2).

The first one will fail, as there is no "-test1" in the string, but the other two will succeed, as there are "-test2" and "-test3" substrings.

Comment: I've added more detail to the original question

Answer (score 0):

First, for the length you need to do for example foodarray.length -1.
How many items do you have in your array (suppose to have)? We need more explanation

Comment: ive added more detail to the original question now